# AdMob - RewardVideo not giving out reward after video is finished

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I have AdMob installed in my sprite kit game and I'm using mediation to get reward videos for the user so that they can earn in game coins but when they watch the video it plays but doesn't give the reward. Now when I try and type out the function it doesn't show a function that gives the reward.

[image]

but when I copy and paste it xcode doesn't give me an error but it still doesn't give me the reward.

[image]

what is the problem and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I show the reward video like so:

```
func showRewardVideoAd() {

    if rewardVideoAd.isReady {

        let vc = self.scene?.view?.window?.rootViewController
        rewardVideoAd.present(fromRootViewController: vc!)

        rewardVideoAd = createRewardAd()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't run the ad through a view controller, you won't know when the ad is finished, obviously.

Comment: @ElTomato I run the video through the scene's rootview controller. please look at the edit i made in my post.

Comment: If you are going to show code, show everything including the class name instead of showing just 3 and a half lines of it in graphics.  Additionally, you are still not fully explaining your situation.

Comment: the function for giving the reward to the the user after doesn't exist when i try and type it in xcode (as seen in the first picture the function isn't on the list) therefore it doesn't run and doesn't give the reward to the player and i'm trying to figure out why this is happening. the second picture displays the function that is supposed to be on the list in picture one, (but isn't) but it is copied from admobs website for reward videos. does that make any sense?